# Remove Specific Line From CSV File by PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to remove specific line from CSV file so I found this code.
But I can't understand that why there is '$myCsv'.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id){
  $file_handle = fopen("out.csv", "w+");
  $myCsv = array();

  while(!feof($file_handle)){
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_hanle, 1024);
    if($id != $line_of_text[1]){
    fputcsv($file_handle, $line_of_text);
    }
  fclose($file_handle);
}
```

Comment: If `$myCsv` is __not__ used anywhere then it is __not needed__.

Comment: You are reading and writing the line back to the same file (except the read has a typo `$file_hanle`).